# Pandas rolling average - Leading and Trailing

Tags: python, pandas

I was wondering if Pandas had a simple syntax to do the Leading and Trailing average calculation?

If I wanted to do a Trailing 30 days and leading 3 days to calculate the rolling average, is there a simple way to do this?

e.g:

| Id | Date | CountA | Avg_vew |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-04-01 | 1050 | 14330.562857142857 |
| 2 | 2022-04-02 | 1283 | 18568.152766952455 |
| 3 | 2022-04-03 | 1071 | 19176.377217553687 |
| 4 | 2022-04-04 | 982 | 20578.77800407332 |
| 5 | 2022-04-05 | 996 | 21000.55 |

The Rolling avg for April1st would be (14330.56+18568.15+19176.37+20578.77)/4  This only includes current date as the older data is not available, In regular scenarios it would go back x(30) number of days back and y(3) number of days forward and calculate mean.

Thanks

Comment: Please [edit] your question and put there sample (small) data and expected output.

Comment: I have updated the description to include an expected output. Thanks

Comment: just use `rolling` method and shift appropriately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `rolling` and `shift`, as suggested by Onyambu in the comments:

```
def custom_rolling_mean(
    df: pd.DataFrame, col: str, window_back: int, window_forward: int, freq: str
) -> pd.DataFrame:
    df["Date"] = pd.to_datetime(df["Date"])
    df = df.set_index("Date")

    df["Avg"] = np.nan

    for i in range(window_forward, -1, -1):
        df["Avg"] = df["Avg"].fillna(
            df[col].rolling(window=f"{window_back}{freq}").mean().shift(-i)
        )
        window_back -= 1

    return df.reset_index()


df = custom_rolling_mean(df, col="Avg_vew", window_back=30, window_forward=3, freq="D")
```

```
        Date  Id  CountA       Avg_vew           Avg
0 2022-04-01   1    1050  14330.562857  18163.467711
1 2022-04-02   2    1283  18568.152767  18730.884169
2 2022-04-03   3    1071  19176.377218  18730.884169
3 2022-04-04   4     982  20578.778004  18730.884169
4 2022-04-05   5     996  21000.550000  18730.884169
```

Comment: @tkansara I noticed there was a mistake in my code: it was setting `window_back` to the length of `df` when this value was smaller, which is a mistake. I've now corrected it (removed `window_back = min(len(df), window_back)`) and the results reflect the correction. Notice that the results now make more sense, since the window for all last 4 rows is the same, so their average must be the same too.